# Is it proper manner to mention a user specifically?

Tags: discussion

I am not here to report about someone or some Ask Ubuntu issue specifically :). Recently in Ask Ubuntu Meta I became popular for a few days and got support from other Ask Ubuntu members (I am glad about that).

What I want to say is; we need a section in the FAQ that says do not mention or blame a specific user for an action they have done and that they can report it to mod's if an action is needed.

I don't want to talk about the past and I don't want to repeat this in the future for any one of us. I am not here to report and I am here to support.

Thank you.

Comment: This may be better suited to the [tag:discussion] tag (not support), you're asking a question in the title but suggesting something in the body (i.e. a [tag:feature-request]). So, I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened before where a user was mentioned by name (an [example here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6660/176889)). It seemed that it was acceptable by fossfreedom and Aditya, as stated in the comments to the question. In this case, the user was editing the post to remove themself, though.

It seems that you should just 'ask nicely' for the author to remove the reference if you feel that it's unecessary or for any other reason, otherwise just leave it be.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am of the opinion that we should not call names *generally*. If it is possible to put our context without mentioning anyone - great. Only when it is not possible to express ourselves unless we specify someone, should we mention that person.

Answer (score 1):

I once wrote a MSO rant where I pointed a specific user and the post was edited:

> meta is the place for discussion, not accusing specific individuals unless necessary.

Hence, unless necessary, I don't consider that pointing individual users should be used.

Comment: That is.. odd. MSO isn't usually like that.