# What should be do with smaller edits?

Tags: discussion, editing

I am going to pick on my own answer but I had 5-6 of these come up in the review queue in a row.

What are we supposed to do with edits that don't really add anything. For example https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/428426 an answer from 2013 had an edit to *maybe* correct some capitalization. I say maybe because it could be argued that capitalization in this case does not matter, and even if it did, it takes research to determine the correct capitalization of wine/Wine/WINE specially in this context.

I have read http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3946/is-it-acceptable-to-make-small-edits but this seems to be a case of making a small insubstantial change to a minor answer. On top of which it creates a lot of "work" to have to review the change if were going to get nit picky and still doesn't really improve anything.

For this edit I rejected, with the appropriate option, but, the question remains. Is there any value in these types of edits (seems not based on other questions on meta), and if not, what can be done to discourage these types of edits?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/428428 is an example of a good edit IMO it made the posting easier to read.

Comment: I think you have to use your judgment. If the edit seems minor and in your opinion does not add value -> reject it. If in doubt, I tend to give credit to the user who took the time to contribute, so I will tend to approve even minor edits. If, however, a user seems to be making so many "minor" edits that I start to feel they are on some sort of personal crusade to fix the INTERNET -> start rejection and or reporting edits / start a discussion on Meta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ever since the too-minor reject reason was removed, it seems the official stand is *it's okay, no matter how minor*. Personally:

- If I *know* the capitalization and/or other pedantry edits are correct/incorrect, I'd accept/reject them.
- If I can't determine the correctness in one Google search + one result followed, skip.

In the particular case of the first edit, I'd *accept and edit*, changing WINE to Wine.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a mere reviewer like you and I saw the same user in the edit queue and approved all of his changes (and added a bit more to one of them if I'm not mistaken), so my humble opinion is that I'm all for making this site a better place to be and if someone is willing to put in the effort, I'd say: let him/her/it!  **:-)**

The user *did* call himself [Grammargeek](https://askubuntu.com/users/336615/grammargeek) for a reason...

Comment: It's not that the edit was "just caps" but that it didn't add value, and as a reviewer I would have to really look up Wine v.s. wine v.s. Wine. I'm not sure which is correct even now. No point in accepting an edit if you can't verify it's correct. For example one could say it should be Wine as that seems to be consistent on the winehq pages, but you could also argue wine is fine because it's a command. Etc, etc, etc. But the question becomes is the difference even worth it? @muru's answer seems to be ok. I guess. I didn't know they removed  the "too small" reason or that the community shifted.

Comment: @coteyr http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116565/too-minor-rejection-reason-needs-either-to-be-reworded-or-removed, and http://winehq.org does use Wine several times. The name is no longer a recursive acronym, so the all-caps version doesn't make sense.

Comment: For me, whether it's Wine, WINE, or wine is irrelevant. It would not alter the meaning.