# Edit "at least 6 characters" restriction prevents useful edit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I got the error

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

while editing a post (I was not sure about writing the link to avoid meta effect)

My edit was only a **format improvement**, turning something like this:

root@host:/path# somecommand somearguments
someoutput
newlineoutput somedetails
newlineagain moreinfo

into something like this:

```
root@host:/path# somecommand somearguments
someoutput
newlineoutput somedetails
newlineagain moreinfo
```

As told before, it was **not possible due to the "6 characters" restriction**, even (if being rigorous) I added 4 characters each line.

So I tried changing (adding) tags, but still did not let me send the edit, which makes sense since I didn't add new content in the body.

So my question/petition is:

While *not counting* spaces may be useful sometimes, is there any way to discern the useful ones? Should the system let me send that edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has [come up a few times before now](/search?q=6+characters). Nothing has changed since then:

- Look for further edits (most posts have more than one issue with them)
- See if there are any actual improvements you could make (rather than just corrections) like sucking in information languishing in comments, etc.
- Benign rephrasings
- HTML comments `<!-- -->`
- And if something's *really* important, you can always drop into the chat room or flag it for moderators and explain the problem.

Essentially what the problem is by design. It's rarely an show-stopping issue so we get along with it.

Comment: I was about to answer myself with a link to [your answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3907/294653) to a similar question, but you were faster :P Anyways it is a workaround, it would be nice to know how many edits of this kind are done (like Wikipedia's "minor edit").

Comment: "would be nice to know how": I agree. But to do so, the SE system would need to track how many times a user attempts, and fails at, making a less-than-6-characters edit. Does SE track that?