# How to suggest an editing only changing one character?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

Looking at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it). I think

> in stead of

should be

> instead of

When I try to save, it prompts:

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to
>   improve in this post?

How can I edit only one character?

Comment: Those kinds of edits are way too minor.  Unless you have edit privileges (which you won't have until you gain enough rep), I don't think you can make these kinds of minor edits.

Comment: You can add a markup comment: `<%- -%>`, but you shouldn't. I have edited it.

Comment: Also visit http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81520

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I edit only one character?

Short answer: You don't.

Long answer: The 6 character requirement has a purpose. Every edit a sub 2k user makes has to be reviewed by at least two normal users (or the original poster or one moderator which have binding votes). Removing one character of whitespace isn't an efficient edit (Are you *sure* there was nothing else to improve?) and wastes reviewer time (Is it really that big of a deal?).

If you find a truly important edit that doesn't make the 6 character limit you can follow any of the steps [outlined in this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/11664/44179), but I wouldn't use those on an edit such as this. Your edit will most likely get rejected.