# How do I edit questions which don't have to be corrected at atleast 6 places?

Tags: discussion, support

I had [suggested edits](https://askubuntu.com/users/278703/faizan?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) to many questions and answers and my edits were genuine: those posts had formatting or grammar mistakes but many of my suggested edits got rejected.

Since many posts had only one mistake (or more but less than 6 characters) and according to AU editing rules there should be edits at 6 places or more otherwise it doesn't allow to save the edits for a low rep user like me. Thus, I edit their question a little bit more (like replacing "ubuntu" with "Ubuntu" and `apt-get` with `sudo apt-get`) so as to make edited characters more than 6 but then my edits are being rejected. On the other hand some user with high rep doesn't have this limit (editing post at 6 or more places), thus their edits are directly visible.

So how to edit such posts for a low rep user like me and if I edit them correct way, why are they being rejected?

Answer (score 2):

You've had a few edits rejected and most approved. Three of those that were rejected had reasons:

One was a "reject and edit" and the reviewer went back to the original and completely reworded it.

The other one is by a person I know well and he just likes to have the link to an external site in plain http://lmgtfy.com style to ensure clear communication that this is off-site and doesn't like the [click here](http://lmgtfy) so he rejected an edit *to his own post himself*...

The other one was rejected by the system due to a subsequent edit...

I'm a reviewer and I'm not perfect.  I try to do the best job I can and so do you.  I normally "approve and edit" unless I've warned you in a comment or the chat room and you keep making the same mistakes. (unless it's just a *really bad edit*, in which case I just reject and edit...)

Other reviewers will just "approve" or "reject" to go through the queue quicker without any subsequent edits, so it's hard to guess for you (or me or anyone else) why some things got rejected.

If you would like more info on particular edits and it was me who rejected, feel free to drop by in the chat room and ping me...

Comment: Hey, 10k time! Welcome to world of deleted posts!

Comment: I very much want to maintain plain readable URLs too - "here" does tell us nothing - it is especially hard for visually impaired people.

Answer (score 1):

From the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/editing):

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> [...]
>
> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. [...]

That rule is there for a reason: if you can't give a post a substantial enough edit **or** you can't [give it a really necessary improvement](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3906/how-to-make-small-but-important-edits?rq=1) (which likely is the reason for the non-acceptance), than the post in first place doesn't *really* need to be edited. Furthermore, as in your [last rejected suggested edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/401149), the post might need to be improved further, and this is another possible reason for the rejections.

Comment: But then why high rep users make the same edit to the post and it is being  accepted and mine being rejected since the posts doesn't need to be edited at 6 or more places thus i have to suggest some extra edits and this limit is not for high rep users (6 character edits) and their edits if at only one place is visible and they get +2 rep. This seems like "string goes stronger and weak goes weaker".

Comment: I updated my answer based on your [last rejected edit suggestion](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/401149), in this case your edit was not good enough. [As you can see](http://askubuntu.com/posts/608255/revisions) the next edit was much more consistent than yours. Plus higher reputation users don't get *any* reputation for reviewing suggested edit (trust me, I'm one of those who can review suggested edits)

Comment: okay thank you brother

Comment: @Faizan: once you get to 2000 rep: no more edit points for you!  Enjoy the rep while you can!  **;-)**